# Making one list from other data using a lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I  have 2 columns of data in an excel sheet - Column A:A is an id number, and column B:B is a binary 1/0 response.  I have > 1, 000 rows of data.

Example

```
0001     1
0002     0 
0003     1 
0004     0
```

On a new sheet in the same workbook I would like to find and list the ID number of everyone whose binary response is 0.

Using the example above, the list I want to populate would be:

```
0002
0004
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why not use a filter? Or pivot table?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, what?

Answer (score 1):

Using @Raystafarian's hint, I would copy all the cells to a new sheet and apply a filter to column B to only select value 0.

Comment: Or the reverse: filter in place, copy the results to the new sheet, then remove the filter.

Comment: Haha thanks everyone; I was completely over-thinking it and trying to use formulae (match; index etc.). Filtering, copying and pasting will work fine!

Comment: Out of interest though - does anyone know a way to do it with formulae?